# How do you download older version of the tar.gz file not present in pypi anymore?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I am looking for an older package of this library in pypi

https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-testing/#history

but the oldest version that I can find is 1.13..
I wanted to download the tar.gz like this https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/7c/ac01c3b07f96cad4cb07efcf41bf688b89fc1ce552488b6c0a37f928eed0/grpcio-testing-1.13.0.tar.gz

But I am specifically looking for the 1.11 version because of some restriction in the dependencies so I cannot upgrade to a latest version?

Any idea where to get an older version of the package or where it might be hosted?

Comment: Maybe start here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.11.0 -- https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.11.0/src/python/grpcio_testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyPI admin here. The earliest release published on PyPI was 1.13.0, earlier releases like 1.11.0 were never published there.

You'll need to build from a source release instead: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.11.0

Comment: Is there a document to rebuilding only the grpcio-testing python package coming from the releases tag of 1.11?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot download what was removed from the site; version 1.13.0rc2 is currently the earliest version: https://pypi.org/simple/grpcio-testing/

You can try to build from sources: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.11.0. The latest micro-release in v1.11 is [v1.11.1](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.11.1).